# Anchor in list elements not filling available space with display:block and height/width set to 100%

Tags: html, css

In the fiddle below i would like to the anchor elements to occupy all of the aviailable space of their parent li elements:

http://jsfiddle.net/nmxmT/

Can't see what i have done wrong :(

Comment: Very similar but less specific about height: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019231/how-do-i-make-an-a-tag-the-size-of-its-parent-li-tag-for-larger-clickable-r

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put the padding on the `a` instead of the `li` and take the width off of the `a`.

http://jsfiddle.net/Gb38x/

Comment: Agreed but should the display:block on the a not then fill up the available space of the parent li?

Comment: The `display:block;` on the `a` is filling up the available space of the parent `li`. However, the extra padding on the original `li` does not count as available space to render content in, padding is applied **outside** of the content. Therefore you need to move the padding into the child element in order to push the `li` out.

Comment: Also - might take a look at this to fix the `border-radius` clipping issues: [http://www.onenaught.com/posts/266/css-inner-elements-breaking-border-radius](http://www.onenaught.com/posts/266/css-inner-elements-breaking-border-radius)