# How do I make an <a> tag the size of it's parent <li> tag for larger clickable region?

Tags: html, css

I would like to do this so that the clickable region on the  tag is size of the `LI`.

My html looks like:

```
<li>
 <a href="#">Link</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Same for table cell, explicitly requires height fill: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966027/make-link-in-table-cell-fill-the-entire-row-height

Answer (score 104, accepted):

As others have said

```
li a { display: block; }
```

should achieve what you're after. **But** you must also remove any padding from the <li> and set it on the <a> instead. For example:

```
li { padding: 0; }
  li a { display: block; padding: 1em; }
```

Comment: Yes, moving the padding (if any) from the li to the a is very important here. A lot of tutorials and examples fail to mention this. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: You could use padding (or margin/border) and use `calc` to calculate the full height: `height: calc(100% - 4px)` - assuming you have `padding: 2px` on that element.

Comment: You could, but you'd be introducing the wholly unnecessary overhead of dynamically calculating the height. Do not underestimate the number of CPU cycles that can be wasted on rendering messy CSS; KISS for maximum responsiveness.

Comment: if you aren't able to change the padding on a parent element for some reason, you can do {margin: -x; padding:x} on the a tag, where x is the padding of its parent

Comment: It does not work for me if I have <a> inside a <div>. I want to make a whole div clickable.

Comment: @Arthur Medeiros If the enclosing <div> has dimensions you can set the <a> to `display:block; height: 100%; width: 100%;`, which will make it fill its parent element completely (provided the parent is a block element which has no padding, and the <a> has no margins and no siblings).

Answer (score 13):

In CSS:

```
li a {
     display: block;
}
```

Of course, you'll want to make your selector more specific than that.

```
<ul>
    <li class="myClass">
        <a href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
</ul>

li.myClass a {
    display: block;
    background-color: #fdd; /* Demo only */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/jmj2k/

Comment: I tried this CSS property earlier, and it only expands the width of the <a> tag horizontally, it doesn't in fact make the <a> tag fill up the <li>

Comment: Then I would say you did not provide enough context for your question. This is the answer for what you provided. If you have a specific implementation in mind, you need to provide that in your question.

Comment: @Brian - The alternative would be to wrap your `LI` content with the `A` tag, depending on the details. However, it's hard to say without seeing that detail.

Answer (score 10):

This will make the entire area clickable.

```
li a { display: block; }
```

Comment: I tried this CSS property earlier, and it only expands the width of the <a> tag horizontally, it doesn't make the <a> tag the size of the parent <li>

Answer (score 2):

Try this css

```
li{
    border:1px solid black;
    height:40px;
}

li a{
    border:1px solid red;
    display:block;
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: adding `height:100%;` with `display:block;` do the trick for me. Thanks +1!

Answer (score 2):

```
li a{     
display: inline-table;
height:95%;    
width: 95%;
}
```

the 95 to anticipate any li margin or padding

Comment: Use this if you need some element beside the a tag. Like an icon or something.

Answer (score 1):

If you currently have this same question you can simply add padding to the right place:

```
li {
  //remove any padding or margin attributes from here
}

li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px; //or however big you want the clickable area to be
}
```

Anchor tags are by default inline elements, so you have to explicitly change them to display as block elements before you can mess with the padding or the margins.

Hope this helps!

Comment: You can also use `display: inline-block;` to make them work *just like* blocks, but while staying in line with other elements.

Answer (score 0):

Just another option I used is create a transparent png image in photoshop and put it inside the anchor tag, make its position absolute and increase its dimensions to fit that parent div you want and you could have a large clickable area.

```
<a href="test.html" />
 <img id="cover_img" src="cover.png" />
</a>

#cover_img {
display: block;
height: 200px;
width: 193px;
position: absolute;
}
```

Might be useful in certain circumstances.