# How do I make an <a> tag the size of it's parent <li> tag?

Tags: html, css

I have the same question that this guy has asked here: [How do I make an <a> tag the size of it's parent <li> tag for larger clickable region?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019231/how-do-i-make-an-a-tag-the-size-of-its-parent-li-tag-for-larger-clickable-r)

However I would like these LI items like an inline menu, so I don't want them to list under each other. How is it aciveable?

Comment: adding `display: inline` didn't work?

Comment: It is "inline" as basic, but the link itself is only clickable.

Comment: you can play with padding, as it gives clickable area

Comment: Yeah. Padding the "a" element will be the solution. Thank you.

Comment: `a{display:block;width:100%;}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are any number of different options, here is one which will be easy to customise: http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/WuhVp/
**HTML**

```
<div id="navcontainer">
<ul id="navlist">
<li id="active"><a href="#" id="current">one</a></li>
<li><a href="#">two</a></li>
<li><a href="#">three</a></li>
<li><a href="#">four</a></li>
<li><a href="#">five</a></li>
</ul> 
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#navcontainer ul
{
padding-left: 0;
margin-left: 0;
background-color: olive;
color: White;
float: left;
width: 100%;
font-family:sans-serif;
}

#navcontainer ul li { display: inline; }

#navcontainer ul li a
{
padding: 0.2em 1em;
background-color: olive;
color: White;
text-decoration: none;
float: left;
border-right: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try 
`li a{ height:100%; width:100%}`
this forces "a" elements under "li" elements to have width and height of its parent

Comment: please put your code in http://jsfiddle.net/ and show us what you have so that we can help you better.

Comment: Need to set display: block in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

The most simple markup could be this:

- the `li`-elements float and therefor are lined up horizontally
- the `a`-tags have `display: block;` to take up the space they have within their parents
- the `ul` has `overflow: hidden;` to clear the float of its schildren

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/w5GUK/)

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Item 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
    overflow: hidden;
    list-style: none;
}

ul > li {
    float: left;
}

ul > li > a {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

set

```
float:left; to the  class controlling li
```

this will help you . and if you want to make the  as clickable as the li's are 
set the property of anchor < a> to

```
display:block;
height:value as you like px;
Width:value as you like px;
```

Answer (score 0):

trick is very simple. keep `padding` of `<a>` larger than `<li>`.

```
li { padding: 0; }
a { padding: 1.1em; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fairly simple method:

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

a {
    display: block;
}
```

Then you can add any heights, widths, line-heights, and paddings accordingly.

Here's an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/BBcEr/2/