# Stretch <a> to fill <li> in menu

Tags: html, css

Having some trouble...  Any idea how I can stretch my `<a>`'s to fill the `<li>`'s they sit in?

I'm trying to make the link easier to click.

Here is my jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/T9nkf/

```
<nav class="main-nav">
    <ul>
        <li class="menu-category"><a href="#">Link</a>
            <ul>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Topic</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Topic</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Topic</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-category"><a href="#">Link</a>
            <ul>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Topic</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Topic</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Topic</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Topic</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-category"><a href="#">Link</a>
            <ul>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Topic</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Topic</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-category"><a href="#">Link</a>
            <ul>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Topic</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Topic</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Topic</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Topic</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019231/how-do-i-make-an-a-tag-the-size-of-its-parent-li-tag-for-larger-clickable-r

Comment: Actually, changing to "display:block;" makes my menu block items and the menu falls apart.  Any other method?

Comment: Adding `width:90%;` to your `.menu-category .menu-item a` seems to achieve the *width* part, but the *height* I don't really know cause `padding` isn't working on your code. I not so good on CSS but I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the tips guys.  Right now im trying to implement the idea of removing padding from the <li>'s and add the padding to the <a>'s.  Instead of using display:block im trying to use display:inline-block.  I'm having difficulty figuring this one out

Comment: is this what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/UqzjX/

Comment: Sorry, no, I'm trying to stretch the <a>'s to fill the light grey area you see when you hover over an element.

Comment: Use display:block on the A-tag and style everything on the A-tag, not the LI.

Comment: Ok, I'm trying to clean that up like you've suggested.

Answer (score 2):

The smartest thing to do is make them (the a's) `display: block`, but then they still don't fill your entire `li`, because the `li` contains padding. Remove the padding from the `li`s. Only give them a size if you need, and apply all the other markup, especially padding, to the `a` elements themselves.

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to not style the li's with the items but remove all their style (apart from necessary ones and only use a elements.

Answer (score 0):

Ok... figured it out!  What I needed was `display:inline-block;`and `padding:0;` set on the `<li>`'s.  Then I let the `<a>`'s handle all the padding, thus filling the `<li>` containers

Solution: http://jsfiddle.net/T9nkf/1/

Thanks for the help guys, couldn't have done it with you.

Answer (score 0):

If you using Bootstrap there is a class called [stretched-link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/helpers/stretched-link/):

```
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card with stretched link</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary stretched-link">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div>
```