# Make anchor whole height of the div for display:block

Tags: html, css

I have simple html:

```
<div class='mydiv'>
    <a href='#'>Link</a>    
<div>
```

and css:

```
div.mydiv { height: 200px; width: 200px; background-color:red; }
div.mydiv a { display:block; color:yellow; background-color:green; }
```

I need anchor occupy entire space of the div, for that I added display:block; to my css, but occupies only top line of the div.

What is wrong and how can I fix that?
Thanks

Comment: For li: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323465/anchor-in-list-elements-not-filling-available-space-with-displayblock-and-heigh, for table cell: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966027/make-link-in-table-cell-fill-the-entire-row-height

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `height:100%` to the anchor CSS:

```
div.mydiv a {
    display:block;
    color:yellow;
    background-color:green;
    height:100%;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/JRukG/)**

Answer (score 2):

You can define the height of your ancor like this

```
a {height: 100%}
```